# Xamarin Forms - Getting Rid of Back Button In Nav Bar

Tags: xamarin.forms

Lets say the first page in the app is the login page and then it takes me to do the main menu screen, is there a way to get rid of the back button in the main menu navigation bar, like get rid of the login page stack?

thank you

Comment: Can you show us the code of your login page?

Answer (score 72):

In Xamarin.Forms 1.3 and greater you can use

```
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
```

In `Xaml` you can add:

```
<ContentPage ....NameSpaces etc....
    NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
    Title="MyPage">
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: @shakin_hand_incision Updated my answer to include `XAML` way

Comment: This still seems to render the space associated with the back button (just without the back button visible). Is there a way to get rid of this space?

Comment: Oh, just found the answer to my own question - to hide the navigation bar completely, in your content page constructor, you would write `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`

Comment: compiled xaml doesn't acept  NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"

Comment: `NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"` compiled successfully and worked very well in visual studio..

Comment: Note: The user can still go back when the back button is pressed on Android.

Answer (score 13):

You can avoid having the Back button if you replace the `Navigation.PushAsync(page)` to `Navigation.PushModalAsync(page)` in your login page's code. Post some code if this somehow doesn't apply

This has to do with how navigation works in the underlying OS (at least in iOS that's the case) - there is a Navigation Controller which serves for pages to transition between each other and have a trace of previous screen so the user can go back.

Comment: What if i want to keep the navigation bar to have toolbaritems?

Comment: toolbar items should be defined for the page, not for the navigation controller

Comment: while you are correct that the back button would not be there, this is not the best solution for simply removing a toolbar button. it would change more than just that.

Answer (score 9):

There are 2 ways to get rid of back button:
1) You can remove navigation bar from Xaml using Xamarin.Forms using below code

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar (this, false);
```

Where `this` stands for current page / form instance.

2) Follow below mentioned steps

- Navigate to login page when the app is loaded with Normal `ContentPage` instance of Login Page
- Navigate to Main page from Login page using `PushModalAsync` and provide the main page instance as `NavigationPage`
- And then from all the other pages, you can use PushAsync and it'll let you navigate to all the pages without any error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can also do `NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"` in the ContentPages XAML

Answer (score 4):

By using CustomRenderer, you call this function in ViewWillAppear in your customized view controller

```
public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
    this.ParentViewController.NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton (true, false); 
    //remember to use ParentViewController to reference to the NavigationViewController (if your contentPage is direct under a navigation controller. I don't know why but Xamarin must have a bug with SetHidesBackButton. If you call with this.NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton(...), it should not work. 
    ... other implements here ...
}
```