# Xamarin Forms - How to do navigation without return

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have two pages: Page A and Page B. I want that the user on my application be able to pass since page A to page B, but I don,t want he to be able to pass since page B to page A. How can I do that?

I tryed to use Navigation Page and deactivate the return Button, but I couldn't find how deactivate it.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to "Navigate" you can set

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new PageB();
```

and override [OnBackButtonPressed()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.OnBackButtonPressed()/)

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
       //back button logic here
       return true;
}
```

Comment: `OnBackButtonPressed()` is only fired when the device back button is pressed (the one on Android devices).  This will not disable the back button that is part of the NavigationPage though.

Comment: You can clear your navigation stack, use "modalpush" or SetHasBackButton look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24935929/xamarin-forms-getting-rid-of-back-button-in-nav-bar

Comment: @cvanbeek I am not using Navigation, so the back button in Navigation Bar  is not present Application.Current.MainPage = new PageB();